# Excel Transform Sub to Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new in VBA and wrote a subroutine that copy-paste cells from one document into another one. Being more precise, I am working in document 1 where I have names of several product (all in column "A"). For these product, I need to look up certain variables (e.g. sales) in a second document.

The subroutine is doing the job quite nicely, but I want to use it as a funcion, i.e. I want to call the sub by typing in a cell "=functionname(productname)".

I am grateful for any helpful comments!
Best, Andreas

```
Sub copy_paste_data()

Dim strVerweis As String               
Dim Spalte                     
Dim Zeile                      
Dim findezelle1 As Range          
Dim findezelle2 As Range          
Dim Variable                    
Dim Produkt                     

'Variable I need to copy from dokument 2
Variable = "frequency"



'Produkt I need to copy data from document 2
Produkt = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)



'path, file and shhet of document 2
Const strPfad = "C:\Users\Desktop\test\"          
Const strDatei = "Bezugsdok.xlsx"           
Const strBlatt = "post_test"              

'open ducument 2
Workbooks.Open strPfad & strDatei
Worksheets(strBlatt).Select

Set findezelle = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Variable)
Spalte = Split(findezelle.Address, "$")(1)

Set findezelle2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Produkt)
Zeile = Split(findezelle2.Address, "$")(2)



'copy cell that I need
strZelle = Spalte & Zeile                  'Zelladresse
strVerweis = "'" & strPfad & "[" & strDatei & "]" & strBlatt & "'!" & strZelle

'close document 2
Workbooks(strDatei).Close savechanges:=False



With ActiveCell
   .Formula = "=IF(" & strVerweis & "="""",""""," & strVerweis & ")"    
   .Value = .Value                                                      
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to create a function that brings just the first 3 letters of a cell:

```
Public Function FirstThree(Cell As Range) As String
    FirstThree = Left(Cell.Text, 3)
End Function
```

And using this in a Excel worksheet would be like:

```
=FirstThree(b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sub works fine and you just want to make it easier to call you can add a hotkey to execute the Macro. In the developer tab click on Macros then Options. You can then add a shortcut key (Crtl + "the key you want" it can be a shortcut key already used like C, V, S, but you will lose those functions (Copy, Paste Save, Print)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pikpa.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! This is exacly how I have implemented it so far. Any suggestions how to get it run as a function is still much appreciated!